# Salary and Rank Discrepency: assistant profs with better records than associates in the same dept

Tags: salary, ranking, assistant-professor

Is there anything to be done when a department has hot young assistant professors with much stronger research records (in books and peer-reviewed publications) than the associate professors? Must the assistant professors just accept that they are less well ranked and less well paid than associates who have been less productive?

Comment: Stronger research records is one thing. Funding might be another. Universities need people who attract funding (NSF, Horizon 2020 for Europe) probably more than paper-producing machines.

Comment: Get to working on their promotions?

Comment: Most of the assistants also have more external grant money than the associates, so that's not the explanation. Working on their promotions sounds reasonable, but oddly enough the associates don't think there's a problem and so aren't motivated to do anything about it. And, the assistants are relatively powerless.

Comment: Not all assistant professors are less well paid than associate professors...

Comment: Prepare to watch the assistants leave for tenured positions elsewhere while your department collapses in on itself due to attrition?

Comment: To expand on StrongBad's point, salary inversion often refers to what happens when assistant professors are hired at a higher salary than existing associate professors. This can happen if the university changes its salary structure (for example to try to attract better faculty.) It is not uncommon for this to happen.

Comment: The salary inversion I'm talking about is in the opposite direction. The associates are better paid than the assistants, even though many (not all) of the assistants have more publications and more grant money than the associates. I suspect Bill Barth is correct, and the assistants will vote with their feet.

Comment: That is not how the term salary inversion is typically used. I have never heard the term rank inversion, but that might be a reasonable use.

Comment: I agree with @StrongBad: you are using the term "salary inversion" in precisely the opposite of the usual manner.  That's pretty confusing.  Underneath that I see a reasonable question, so I suggest you edit to clarify.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for a better word? Inequity seems accurate, but perhaps unnecessarily inflammatory.

Comment: If the assistant professors are unhappy, they should apply for and get associate professor offers from another, more prestigious, university. Then the department will have to respond if it wants to keep them.

Comment: **Differential**?  **Discrepancy**?

Answer (score 2):

Position in a university, and consequently salary, is not simply a function of being "hot and young", grant funding, and publications. But there are many other factors you may be missing. For example, the associate professors in your department may be teaching larger classes (under the assumption that the department tries to give the assistants smaller classes while they build a resume for their tenure decision); they may also, with more experience, be better teachers. And they will almost certainly have far higher service loads -- sitting on committees, mentoring, reviewing duties, etc. All of these are things that are valuable to a department and that is worth a certain amount of salary. But it's hardly visible from the outside, even though it definitely diminishes your ability to do research and publish a lot.

Finally, the associate professors have one less promotion to look forward to, and consequently a lower salary *potential*. For example, an assistant professor paid 5% less than an associate will earn 5% *more* after promotion, which translates into a quite significant sum over the remaining work life.

I do get your point, and there definitely are departments that have significantly improved and where the young crop is better than the old, and should expect to be paid better when comparing *at the same stage in their careers*. But it's hard to determine a "fair salary" between different ranks if all you reduce things to is grants & publications.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to think that 'top' assistant professors carry the whole university.  They are one of many variables that play a role in the running and success of a university.  Who do you think pay the salary of professors? Hint: it's not high quality papers.  Answer: coursework students.  How do you get coursework students? for one, you have to teach well, have a well-run university; good admin, programs, reputation for teaching, community engagement, getting jobs, etc.  These 'other' people you seem to think the ass/prof are better than actually created the environment that allow the ass/prof to flourish.  Who do you think should get the higher pay?  The leach (newbie) or the host?

Comment: You seem to think that the assistant profs aren't teaching the 800-person service classes. You think wrong. In fact, the person I'm most thinking of (the assistant with the strongest research record) also teaches the dept's largest class. And teaches it every semester because its the dept's major service class. It is certainly true, however, that the associates carry more of the administrative burden. But, then this same person asked for consideration for early tenure (thereby opening them up to pick up some of that administrative burden), they were told they had to wait their turn...

Comment: ...and that it didn't matter how good their record was. They just had to wait. That is the source of the intra-departmental frustration for that the assistant, as well as a few others who (having watched his request) haven't even asked.